Create / adjust plot to raster extent - R Studio
This probably a fairly simple fix but have not managed to find a solution, being really new to R.
I have imported a canopy height model raster into R and done basic plotting of the raster
chm <- terra::rast("filepath")
plot(chm)

The raster comes out looking like below - so very small image. How can I adjust the plot so it covers the full extent of the raster only, so I will be able to actually see the image?


Hard to help without knowing anything about your data. Maybe it has data out to those coordinates? Can you edit your Q and add some summary info, eg the output from print(chm) and summary(chm)?

It's not entirely clear without that little information, what your issue is here.
But mainly the extend of the plot doesn't match, what you want to focus one.
If your extend is changed from a previous plot this may already be enough:
plot(chm, ext=ext(chm))

There can also be other reasons, such as that what you get plottet is actually the rasters extend, but it's NA in the other regions (which is a plausible explanation, if your CHM classification was maybe only runn on a parcell and clipped to it.
In such a case, you may manualy adjust the margins of your plot by setting the xlim and ylim arguments. It would look like this:
plot(chm, xlim(A,B), ylim(C,D))

where you set the desired extend by replacing:

A with your minimum X value
B with your maximum X value
C with your minimum Y value, and
D with your maximum Y value


Its probably worth waiting for replies to comments on this, I'm not sure answering with "If you mean this, the answer is A, else the answer might be B" is a good idea here. We'd still expect the OP to clarify and better that's done in the question than the answer...
